# INNER JOIN after a satisfied condition

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I am trying to create a `SELECT` statement that will output a Comma Separated Values file. I tried using `INNER JOIN` to combine rows from different tables, but my problem is, not all rows from table 2 contain the field that I need. That is why I am getting a MySQL Warning.

Is it possible to create a `SELECT` statement that will contain `INNER JOIN` only if it satisfies a condition. Will this be possible?

CODE:

```
mysql_connect($server, $login, $password);
mysql_select_db($db);

$fp = fopen($filename, "w");


$query = "SELECT t1.title, t1.introtext, t2.jr_street, t2.jr_city, t2.jr_state, t2.jr_postalcode, t2.jr_country, t3.created, t3.name, t3.title, t3.comments, t4.ratings_sum, t4.ratings_qty FROM $table1 t1
                    INNER JOIN $table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.contentid
                    INNER JOIN $table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.pid
                    INNER JOIN $table4 t4  ON t1.id = t4.reviewid
";

$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$first_line = true; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) { 
    if ($first_line) { 
        fputcsv($fp, array_keys($row)); 
        $first_line = false; 
    } 
    fputcsv($fp, $row); 
}
```

Comment: Please post the schemas of the tables and the query you tried to write. Also, tag the question with the DBMS you're using (mysql, oracle, mssql). And PHP seems irrelevant.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "not all rows from table 2 contain the field that I need". All rows in a table have the same columns.

Comment: If your problem is that some of the rows may not have matching _values_ in other tables, you want an `OUTER JOIN` rather than an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. `mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/website/public_html/directory/test.php on line 37` Here's the warning that I am getting.

Comment: That means you have a syntax error in the query. When `$res` returns `false` you need to print `mysql_error()` to see the problem.

Comment: Changing from inner to outer join won't solve that.

Comment: Oh. I see. How will I do this? Before `INNER JOIN` a row, I must check first if the row matches a specific value.

Comment: That's what INNER JOIN does -- it finds all the rows that match a value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30660/discussion-between-barmar-and-jetpro)

Comment: I tried using `OUTER JOIN` but it's echoing "Query is empty". I also tried `INNER JOIN`, it displays this error `mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in /home/website/public_html/directory/test2.php on line 25`.

Comment: I showed you earlier that you have to check the return value of mysql_query(). Any time you get that error it means you're not doing error checking.

Comment: Oh, that's a different problem. You're not giving a proper string as the argument to mysql_query(). Add your current code to the question, you seem to have gotten something really messed up.

Comment: You're calling mysql_query() twice. The argument to mysql_query is supposed to be a string, not the return value of another query.

Comment: It should be `$res = mysql_query("SELECT ...") or die (mysql_error());`

Comment: I did not notice that. Now, I tried using INNER JOIN, I am not getting any error, but it results to a blank CSV file. I also tried OUTER JOIN. It produces this error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN weew_jreviews_content t2 ON t1.id = t2.contentid ' at line 2`

Comment: @Barmar, I did not notice that. Now, I tried using INNER JOIN, I am not getting any error, but it results to a blank CSV file. I also tried OUTER JOIN. It produces this error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN weew_jreviews_content t2 ON t1.id = t2.contentid ' at line 2`

Comment: Sorry, the correct syntax is `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or just `LEFT JOIN`.